# What's the meaning of rosws merge?

Tags: ros, rosws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [rosjava_core 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT documentation](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html).

What's the meaning of this command?

```
  rosws merge /opt/ros/electric/.rosinstall
```

Is it suitable for any ROS version?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41715/what%27s-the-meaning-of-rosws-merge?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosws merge merges your local .rosinstall with another rosinstall file. Often projects define several stacks or packages to download from different sources in a single xyz.rosinstall file. Rather than copying the contents of that file into your local .rosinstall file, you can use rosws merge.

Calling

```
rosws merge foo.rosinstall
```

is equivalent to calling

```
rosinstall . foo.rosinstall
```

The rosws command works with any ROS version.

Also see the rosws documentation:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosws

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-17**:
I have already install ROS electric. Why I still need to rosinstall /opt/ros/electric/.rosinstall ? Thank you~

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-17**:
Please have a look at the [ros overlay installation page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) for more information on how to properly set up a ros overlay. You need to merge /opt/ros/electric/.rosinstall to your current workspace if you want to use stacks installed as debian pkgs.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-17**:
I understand I always use a cumbersome way of ROS. But I still don't understand what's the effect of rosinstall /opt/ros/electric/.rosinstall? Thank you~

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-17**:
A ros workspace is a directory that contains a .rosinstall file that points to all repositories you installed from source, to local directories that should be part of your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. `rosws merge` merges the content of another rosinstall file with your workspace.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-17**:
So what your meaning is 'rosws merge' generate the .rosinstall which has all paths including /opt/ros/electric/.rosinstall, then I add setup.bash to bashrc in order to replace the path of /opt/ros/electric/.rosinstall? Thank you~